# Identifying and understanding this PRNG

Tags: random

I have this random number generator, and have had it for quite some time, but despite how much I use it I don't really understand it.

```
public static int Random(int x)
{
    x = x + seed;
    x = (x << 13) ^ x;
    return (x * (x * x * 15731 + 789221) + 1376312589) & 0x7fffffff;
}
```

It works really well for my purposes - it takes an integer and just spits out another random integer. It doesn't rely on a state, nor does it rely on its last output like so many linear congruential generators.

What type of generator is this? I'd like some terms that I can google to understand and learn more about it. What family of PRNG does it belong to? How/why does it work?

Comment: You shouldn't put images of text in your posts. Always post the code itself so it's easier to copy/paste and to search. I edited your question, you can verify I didn't do any mistake.

Comment: If you can afford the lower performance, I'd consider using a proper PRF (pseudo-random-function) instead.

Comment: Can anyone suggest how I could modify this function to accommodate 2 and 3 input integers?

Comment: Combine the integers into one according to your requirements (xor? add? multiply?), then call this function with the result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A bit of poking around on Google suggests that this is a *Linear Feedback Shift Register* or LFSR.  It's apparently commonly used to produce noise for shaders.

**Further Reading**
[Noise and Pseudo Random Number Generator in GLSL](http://www.geeks3d.com/20100831/shader-library-noise-and-pseudo-random-number-generator-in-glsl/)
[Linear-feedback shift register](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear-feedback_shift_register)

Comment: @MasonWheeler Depends on the definition you're using. For example one could consider `/dev/urandom` a PRNG because it's not truly random, but it's not deterministic because it implicitly seeds (and frequently reseeds) itself from various true RNGs.

Comment: @CodesInChaos So what happens when it gets the same seed?

Comment: For perlin noise, you essentially need a hash function, not a stateful PRNG. Since this is cheap hash, it's suitable for that purpose.

Comment: Good links.  I think it's important to note that you can imply from the second link that these are not recommended for crypto purposes unless you really know what you are doing.

Comment: LFSRs are used any time you need a data source that's mostly random at face value, but is still deterministic. If you were developing a wireless transmission protocol for example, an LSFR output is random enough to simulate arbitrary data, but deterministic so that you can debug transmission errors because you know what you should be receiving.

Comment: Can anyone suggest how I could modify the function to take 2 and 3 input integers?

Comment: @user2312610: That doesn't make much sense for an LFSR.

Comment: @whatsisname: as in; how could I get it to do what it currently does, but taking the signature public static float Random(int x, int y, int z) - where it spits out random numbers unique to that combination of 3 numbers

Comment: @user2312610 How big is `int`?  If you have an integer type that is quadruple the size, you can make your three ints significant digits of that larger size, but you would have to completely rewrite the function with new constants.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: they're 32 bit integers - and my constants are just large primes I plucked off a graph from memory. How would I encode said significant digits? I can't say I've done much work with bitwise operations before

Comment: @user2312610: Sounds like you need a 96 bit LFSR (for three 32-bit integers).  According to [this table](http://courses.cse.tamu.edu/csce680/walker/lfsr_table.pdf), you can build one using taps at positions 96, 90, 87 and 86.  See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7830379/how-to-implement-128-bit-linear-feedback-shift-register-with-byte-element-array

Comment: @user2312610: while that doesn't make much sense, in any case, don't change the function, but decide a way to turn your three numbers into a single number then feed that to a LSFR of sufficient size.

Comment: @whatsisname: The "way" would be x^64 + y^32 + z, assuming you have a data type large enough to put that in.  Or simply a 3-element array of 32 bit numbers, and write an LSFR using those.

Answer (score 4):

To be clear, this doesn't produce a random number.  What it does (I expect) is produce wildly different numbers for integers that are close to each other.  The way it does that is by overflowing the int by creating numbers that are bigger (absolute value) than the 32 bit range can support at least once.  The shift and xor appear to expand the input over 32 bits and the multiplications and additions cause it to overflow and improve the distribution.  I am not a mathematician but I believe this could be described as a [chaotic function](http://functionspace.com/topic/233/What-are-some-examples-of-a-chaotic-system-).

I ran some numbers through Java with seed of 13.  Seems pretty well distributed:

[image: distribution of results for inputs 0 -> 10000]

Locally too:

[image: zoomed in]

Comment: PRNG = Pseudo Random Number Generator. The "pseudo" implies it's not truly random.

Comment: @8bittree Of that, I am well aware but the comment "takes an integer and just spits out another random integer" suggests to me it's worth pointing out explicitly.

Comment: @jimmyjames "random" was just lazy short-hand - i know it's only pseudorandom

Comment: @user2312610 I figured you did but this often poorly understood and other people could read that and be confused.

Comment: Bloody hell - thanks for the graphics and stuff - that's incredible.

Comment: @user2312610 cool, glad you liked them.  It didn't notice that `& 0x7fffffff` was stripping off the sign bit until I saw the graph.

Comment: @JimmyJames Could you suggest how I might adapt the function to accommodate 2 and 3 input integers?

Comment: @user2312610 I can think of some ways but I'm not sure what your goal is.  Care to elaborate?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41568/discussion-between-user2312610-and-jimmyjames).

Comment: @Justin Ha! I made them in Excel how embarrassing is that?

Comment: Re, "using x as an exponent":  The `^` operator in Java is not exponentiation; it's bit-wise XOR.

Comment: @jameslarge my bad, I'll fix.